# Why does the Opentelemetry exporter to NewRelic is failing

Tags: monitoring, metrics, newrelic, open-telemetry

I have set up an Opentelemetry collector which exports metrics to New Relic, but it is giving me the following error:

```
exporterhelper/queued_retry.go:215  Exporting failed. Will retry the request after interval.
{
    "kind": "exporter",
    "name": "otlp",
    "error": "rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded",
    "interval": "7.202545441s"
}
```

This is my `collector.yaml` file:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
      http:

exporters:
  logging:
    loglevel: debug
  awsxray:
  awsemf:
    namespace: PaymentService
  otlp:
    endpoint: ${NEW_RELIC_OPENTELEMETRY_ENDPOINT}
    headers:
      api-key: ${NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY}

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [otlp]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [otlp]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [otlp]
```

I am not sure if whether this is an Opentelemetry issue or a New Relic one.

Also, these are other logs that are showing up:

```
warn    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:191  [transport] transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to read frame: read tcp 127.0.0.1:4317->127.0.0.1:33316: read: connection reset by peer {
    "grpc_log": true
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If that message is intermittent, its likely that isn’t any issue with either the collector or new relic. The internet has intermittent issues - the customers network may temporarily have connectivity issues or low throughput causing the request to timeout. As indicated in the error message, the request will be retried after some interval.
If the message is consistent, they might be misconfiguring the otlp exporter or their network may not be configured correctly to connect to the new relic OTLP endpoint.

Comment: It ends up by resetting the connection (I have updated the question)